# Marklogic 8 : delete in bulk

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I'm using Marklogic 8.0.6 and I'm wondering if we can delete in bulk method. For example, I want to delete 150 000 documents that I can identify with a list of URI or with common properties (fields COUNTRY=US and COLOR=BLUE).

Is there a way to use a ML native function (in node.js) to perform these DELETE in bulk mode (for both cases : list of URIs and common properties) ? For latencies reasons, it's obvious that 150 000 API calls are not performant.

Thanks,
Romain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple options.

- if there is a [collection or directory that you can delete](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/node-dev/documents#id_80368), you can do that
- if you know the URIs of the documents to delete, you can pass a list of them to the delete command; if there are too many for one transaction, you can do a multi-statement transaction to get them all.
- you can also [create a service extension](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/node-dev/extensions), send over the query parameters, and then your extension can run a query and delete the results

---

Updating with additional detail for deleting multiple documents. [documents.remove](http://docs.marklogic.com/jsdoc/documents.html#remove) takes either a string or an array of strings for the `uris` parameter:

```
db.documents.remove(
  ['/doc1.json', '/doc2.json']
)
```

Comment: "if you know the URIs of the documents to delete, you can pass a list of them to the delete command; " => how you can send a list ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the read/write attributes of forests, or direct-forest-placement options to document-insert to arrange for documents to 'migrate' to a new forest (or out of a forest), then simply detach the forest.